# How to load FileSystemResources from jar

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring-boot. and want to load resources from directory. following code works fine for filesystem environment.
But gives FileNotFoundException when working with Jar,because Spring tries to access a file system path, but it can not access a path in JAR.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MongoDBMigrator migrator;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            migrator.runScripts(ctx.getResources("classpath:db/*.js"));
    }   
}
```

what need to be done to make it work with jar as well

Comment: is your jar in the classpath ?

Comment: @rahul singh : yes. its there

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileFromJarFile);
```

If test.txt was in the root of your JAR file, you'd use:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
```

assumes the class is in the same JAR file as the resource, I believe

Comment: InputStream is used for single resource. I want to read multiple resources as file not as inputstream. because for further operation i need file path , filename etc

Comment: @suvarnaChavan Yes it is used for single resource use can use a List of InputStream if the Resource name is same